# initial quantity for product variations

Tags: woocommerce

I found this code which allows me to set an initial quantity for simple products: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/

It leaves me the freedom to reduce the quantity. (eg. initial quantity = 5 and I could reduce to 3)

But for products with variations it is only possible to set a minimum quantity, not an initial quantity. Unfortunately it is not possible to reduce items.

I've tried to find a solution to only set the initial quantity for product variation, but there seems not to be one.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You can make use of the product removal link from the cart page `WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key )`

Comment: This solutions seems only to remove the entire position of a product from the cart. But I need to set an initial quantity of a product with variations before I put it into the cart.

Comment: Then please explain your scenario and expected outcome in detail.

Comment: When opening a product page (for variable product) the initial quantity needs to be 5. I then need to be able to reduce the quantity to less than 5 before adding the product to the cart. (With above mentioned code this already works for simple products but not for variable products).

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to set the initial amount to 5 and users are allowed to reduce or increase as per their requirement then you just need to set the input value to your desired one.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value']    = 5;    // your desired value
    return $args;
}
```

**Update**

By default you are not allowed to do so. But if you insist then you can make a work around. But beware, this might hurt.

If your theme has the copy of woocommerce template files (generally in a folder named woocommerce in the root of your template directory). Navigate to `[your-theme-directory]/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php` file and search for qty class in the number input field. Then remove it.

Again I would like to warn you some functionality depends on this class, you can see that in add-to-cart-variations.js file in the plugins assets/js folder. You need to be prepared for that.

Comment: this only works for simple products. not for variations.